# Script to automatically delete words from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have very little coding experience so please bear with me. I am trying to write a script that will check every cell in a google sheet if a cell contains a certain word it will either delete all contents from that cell or preferably will revert the cell back to its previous state before that edit. For example, say I am looking for the word “new” and a cell contains “this is a test sentence” and then is edited to say “this is a test sentence with the word new added” I would want that cell to be cleared or go back to “this is a test sentence”. The code below works, but only if the cell has the exact word in it. So if a cell just contains “new” or “car” it clears the cell, but if the cell contains “new car” nothing happens.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  return e.value ? (listOfWords(e.value) !== -1 ? e.range.clearContent() : null) : null;  
}

function listOfWords(word) {
  var listEN = ['new','car'];
  return listEN.indexOf(word);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete the words in your list.  I don't know how big you real list will get but that length will have significant impact upon the performance.  I'm splitting the cell content up with white space or period as in the regex `(/(\s|\.)/)`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    //e.source.toast("If1")
    const list = ["new","car","red","green","blue"];
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(list));
    const wA = e.value.split(/(\s|\.)/);//splitting on while space which apparently does not include period.
    let d = 0;
    let i = 0;
    do {
      let w = wA[i];
      //e.source.toast("If2")
      let idx = list.indexOf(w);
      if(~idx) {
        //Logger.log('b4splice: i: %s, word: %s idx: %s',i,w,idx);
        wA.splice(i,1);
        i--;
        //Logger.log('wA: %s i: %s idx: %s',wA.join(" "),i,idx);
        e.range.setValue(wA.join(" "));
      } else {
        i++;
      }
      //Logger.log('b4while: i: %s word: %s idx: %s',i,w,idx)
    } while(i < wA.length);
  }
}//Was taking less than 2 seconds to do even with all of the loggers turned on
```